# AudioSystem downloads partial file

Tags: java, kotlin, audio

I'm trying to download a file using AudioSystem. However, it fails to download the complete file. I've tried with other audio files and can replicate the bug with them. I've also tried various hosting services, and it didn't help.

There are no exceptions thrown. This was working correctly a few weeks ago, so I'm not sure what happened since then.

Would appreciate some help since I'm not too familiar with handling audio files.

```
import java.io.File
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    downloadAudio()
}

fun downloadAudio() {
    val localFile = File("/tmp/input_audio.wav")

    val audioUrl = URL("https://srv-store1.gofile.io/download/vj9dHc/my_audio_recording_wav.wav")

    try {
        val audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(audioUrl)
        val inputAudioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioUrl)
        inputAudioStream.use {
            AudioSystem.write(inputAudioStream, audioFileFormat.type, localFile)
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        throw ex
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using AudioSystem at all?  You’re just downloading a file;  the type is irrelevant.  [Open the URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) and [copy it to a file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

Comment: Well, AudioSystem was more specific to audio files, which is why I used it. I can switch to a number of other alternatives, but was wondering why this wasn't working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Understandable.  In this case using URL.openStream will remove the chance of AudioSystem’s analysis introducing issues.